# PHP function gettext() is only translating in en_US (English)

Tags: php, localization, gettext

```
$folder = "locale";
$domain = "messages";
$encoding = "UTF-8";

putenv("LC_ALL=" . $language); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

bindtextdomain($domain, $folder); 
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, $encoding); 

textdomain($domain);
```

$language has been previously set to fr_FR (i checked) and whenever i call `echo _("HELLO_WORLD");` (for an example), it only returns translation in english (en_US). I've properly set all the folders ( path to french .mo file is `locale/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo` ), I've translated "HELLO_WORLD" both into english and french (using Poedit), i tried adding ".UTF-8" to the $language string, but nothing works, it still only shows english translation. I also tried restarting Apache web server every time i made changes to .mo files. Does someone know why does this occur?

I'm using Win10 64bit and XAMPP v3.2.2.

Comment: Is your MO file under LC_MESSAGES subfolder? path should be `locale/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo`

Comment: Yes, as i said, i've properly set all the folders. I have spent like 6 hours yesterday figuring out why does this problem occur and i still have no clue what to do...

Comment: then you should add what "properly set up" entailed so nobody else has to ask the same question.